# Run build for C++ code (make) in Python script

Tags: python, c++, shell, scripting

I keep running into an error when I want to compile code written in C++ using Python script to run "make" in x directory. Compiling the code takes about few seconds so I am using time module to have the script sleep for 60 seconds to finish compiling the code.

**Here is the code:**

```
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep
def make_ut_adsmain():
        os.system("make ../../ads/main/unittest")
        # call(["ls", "-l"])
        sleep(60)

make_ut_adsmain()

# Run other functions when compiled...
```

**Error**

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../../ads/main/unittest'.  Stop.
```

The code never really compiles because the rest of the code depends on the log file which never gets created. Please guide me.

Comment: Does running make manually in that directory work? This doesn't seem indicative of python not being able to find the Makefile

Comment: yup it does. I just able to resolve it. Posted the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured it out and able to run the build process by using the following code:

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
def make_ut_adsmain():
        subprocess.Popen(["make"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="../../ads/main/unitest")
        sleep(60)

make_ut_adsmain()
```

Note, the previous solution works only if you need to bypass errors. The correct way to do is the following. Check @tdelaney comment and read more on python docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep
def make_ut_adsmain():
        subprocess.check_all(["make"], cwd="../../ads/main/unitest")

make_ut_adsmain()
```

Comment: This has major problems. You fix one problem by changing `cwd` but you make `stdout` a pipe but then don't read it (make will deadlock if it prints a bunch of data) and then you just sleep an arbitrary 60 seconds instead of waiting for the call to finish. As a minimum, do `subprocess.check_call(["make"], cwd="../../ads/main/unitest")`) and get rid of the sleep completely.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney : I read the docs and it makes sense. But your minimum solution gives me error: subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

Comment: That's great! It means that the make failed and you need to figure that out. Your original script silently ignored errors.

Comment: @tdelaney I now get it. But for my testing purpose on my dev machine, I still need to stick to my original solution because there is an error I need to ignore and execute running the compiled binary file. Thanks for the advice! (Also, it'd be great if you can remove downvote) as this doesn't apply to what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I think you also want to remove the sleep... then it looks good and I'll remove the downvote.